# Play audio file to iOS Simulator Mic

Tags: ios

Is it possible at all to play a audio file directly to the iOS simulator?

In essence, redirect the audio output to the audio input on the computer so the iOS simulator could receive the audio through its mic?

Comment: do you mean mac mic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was using Rogue Amoeba's [Sound Flower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) and creating new channels of audio. Then going into Mac's Audio MIDI Setup app under utilities to set the virtual channel to be both the input and output, allowing the audio file that I'm playing on iTunes to directly feed into the microphone of the simulator.

Comment: How you are setting things here? Is there another way to do this? Where did you find this solution?

Answer (score 1):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2104726?tstart=0

iOS Simulator does not support audio recording, you should use read device.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1

Hardware Limitations While most of the functionality of iOS devices can be simulated in iOS Simulator, there are some hardware features that must be tested directly on a device. The hardware features that cannot be simulated are:

Accelerometer

Gyroscope
Camera
Proximity Sensor

Microphone Input

Comment: Not trying to record anything but rather just simply test voice recognition. The simulator can take inputs from the internal built in mic of my laptop. I was wondering if there is a way to directly play audio into that input instead of having me speak something

Comment: FYI microphone input/output is supported in simulator now. https://help.apple.com/simulator/mac/current/#/deve63797392